# Azure Load Testing: How to create a test using Terrform?

Tags: azure, jmeter, terraform-provider-azure, azure-load-testing

I have created a test in Azure Load Testing using Azure CLI

> az group create --name sample-rg  --location westus2
>
> az load create --name sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg
> --location westus2
>
> az load test create --test-id sample-test-id --load-test-resource
> sample-resource --resource-group sample-rg --display-name "Find IP"
> --description "Test description" --test-plan IPLoadTesting.jmx --engine-instances 1 --env rps=2 count=1

[image]

While terraform allow us to create the Azure Load Testing resource
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/load_test, I don't find an option to create a Test within the Azure Load Testing using Terraform. Is this possible?

Comment: If the resource isn't available, you can ask for a feature or contribute via github. In the meantime, you can use [azapi](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Azure/azapi/latest/docs) resource by invoking the API with payload..

Comment: Try this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.loadtestservice/2022-12-01/loadtests?pivots=deployment-language-terraform to create using Azapi.

Comment: I tried to use Azapi, since Azure Load Tests are configured via the Data plane this doesn't work. Afterward, I tried to use some Terraform REST API (direct calls), but this failed since you had to upload JMX files in octet streams (and octet was not supported by that library). I ended up writing a simple console application that reads some information from settings files and applies the load tests to the required stages. Maybe that saves someone some hassle